# Kafka Docker and port forwarding from 9092 to 9093

Tags: maven, docker, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, maven-docker-plugin

I have configured Kafka + ZooKeeper via maven docker plugin https://dmp.fabric8.io/:

```
<image>
    <name>wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest</name>
    <alias>zookeeper</alias>
    <run>
        <ports>
            <port>2181:2181</port>
        </ports>
    </run>
</image>

<image>
    <name>wurstmeister/kafka:1.0.0</name>
    <alias>kafka</alias>
    <run>
        <ports>
            <port>9092:9092</port>
        </ports>
        <links>
            <link>zookeeper:zookeeper</link>
        </links>
        <env>
            <KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME>127.0.0.1</KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME>
            <KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT>zookeeper:2181</KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT>
        </env>
    </run>
</image>
```

On this configuration, everything is working fine.

Right now I need to change the Kafka port(forwarded port for the host system) from `9092` to `9093`.

In `application.properties` of my Spring Boot application I have added the following line:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=127.0.0.1:9093
```

And also changed the configuration for Kafka image to:

```
<image>
    <name>wurstmeister/kafka:1.0.0</name>
    <alias>kafka</alias>
    <run>
        <ports>
            <port>9093:9092</port>
        </ports>
        <links>
            <link>zookeeper:zookeeper</link>
        </links>
        <env>
            <KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME>127.0.0.1</KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME>
            <KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT>zookeeper:2181</KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT>
        </env>
    </run>
</image>
```

and faced the following error:

```
2017-11-22 18:18:16.453 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : Starting Kafka producer I/O thread.
2017-11-22 18:18:16.453 DEBUG 17532 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : Kafka producer started
2017-11-22 18:18:16.456 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Initialize connection to node -1 for sending metadata request
2017-11-22 18:18:16.456 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Initiating connection to node -1 at 127.0.0.1:9093.
2017-11-22 18:18:16.457 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-sent
2017-11-22 18:18:16.457 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-received
2017-11-22 18:18:16.458 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Added sensor with name node--1.latency
2017-11-22 18:18:16.458 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
2017-11-22 18:18:16.458 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Completed connection to node -1.  Fetching API versions.
2017-11-22 18:18:16.458 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Initiating API versions fetch from node -1.
2017-11-22 18:18:16.470 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Recorded API versions for node -1: (Produce(0): 0 to 5 [usable: 3], Fetch(1): 0 to 6 [usable: 5], Offsets(2): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], Metadata(3): 0 to 5 [usable: 4], LeaderAndIsr(4): 0 to 1 [usable: 0], StopReplica(5): 0 [usable: 0], UpdateMetadata(6): 0 to 4 [usable: 3], ControlledShutdown(7): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], OffsetCommit(8): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], OffsetFetch(9): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], FindCoordinator(10): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], JoinGroup(11): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], Heartbeat(12): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], LeaveGroup(13): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], SyncGroup(14): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DescribeGroups(15): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], ListGroups(16): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], SaslHandshake(17): 0 to 1 [usable: 0], ApiVersions(18): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], CreateTopics(19): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DeleteTopics(20): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DeleteRecords(21): 0 [usable: 0], InitProducerId(22): 0 [usable: 0], OffsetForLeaderEpoch(23): 0 [usable: 0], AddPartitionsToTxn(24): 0 [usable: 0], AddOffsetsToTxn(25): 0 [usable: 0], EndTxn(26): 0 [usable: 0], WriteTxnMarkers(27): 0 [usable: 0], TxnOffsetCommit(28): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeAcls(29): 0 [usable: 0], CreateAcls(30): 0 [usable: 0], DeleteAcls(31): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeConfigs(32): 0 [usable: 0], AlterConfigs(33): 0 [usable: 0], UNKNOWN(34): 0, UNKNOWN(35): 0, UNKNOWN(36): 0, UNKNOWN(37): 0)
2017-11-22 18:18:16.471 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Sending metadata request (type=MetadataRequest, topics=boot.test) to node -1
2017-11-22 18:18:16.477 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : Updated cluster metadata version 2 to Cluster(id = I2vTDIF_RYacc2xxU2iAyQ, nodes = [127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 1001 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = boot.test, partition = 0, leader = 1001, replicas = [1001], isr = [1001])])
2017-11-22 18:18:16.492 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Initiating connection to node 1001 at 127.0.0.1:9092.
2017-11-22 18:18:17.115 DEBUG 17532 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Added sensor with name node-2147482646.bytes-sent
2017-11-22 18:18:17.115 DEBUG 17532 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Added sensor with name node-2147482646.bytes-received
2017-11-22 18:18:17.115 DEBUG 17532 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Added sensor with name node-2147482646.latency
2017-11-22 18:18:17.119 DEBUG 17532 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : Connection with /127.0.0.1 disconnected

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:50) ~[kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:95) ~[kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:359) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:326) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:432) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:232) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:208) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:168) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:358) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:310) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:297) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1078) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1043) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:571) [spring-kafka-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_152]

2017-11-22 18:18:17.119 DEBUG 17532 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Node 2147482646 disconnected.
2017-11-22 18:18:17.120  WARN 17532 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Connection to node 2147482646 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2017-11-22 18:18:17.120 DEBUG 17532 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerNetworkClient        : Cancelled JOIN_GROUP request {api_key=11,api_version=2,correlation_id=3,client_id=consumer-1} with correlation id 3 due to node 2147482646 being disconnected
2017-11-22 18:18:17.120  INFO 17532 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Marking the coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147482646 rack: null) dead for group boot
2017-11-22 18:18:17.221 DEBUG 17532 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Sending GroupCoordinator request for group boot to broker 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 1001 rack: null)
2017-11-22 18:18:17.221 DEBUG 17532 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Initiating connection to node 1001 at 127.0.0.1:9092.
2017-11-22 18:18:17.494 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Added sensor with name node-1001.bytes-sent
2017-11-22 18:18:17.494 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Added sensor with name node-1001.bytes-received
2017-11-22 18:18:17.494 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Added sensor with name node-1001.latency
2017-11-22 18:18:17.495 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : Connection with /127.0.0.1 disconnected
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Why NetworkClient is still trying to connect to `9092`?

```
2017-11-22 18:18:16.492 DEBUG 17532 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Initiating connection to node 1001 at 127.0.0.1:9092.
```

**UPDATED**

I also tried the following `env` properties:

```
<env>
    <KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME>127.0.0.1</KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME>
    <KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT>9093</KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT>
    <KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT>zookeeper:2181</KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT>
</env>
```

this way I have another `LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE` error:

```
2017-11-22 22:11:54.482 DEBUG 8988 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : Starting Kafka producer I/O thread.
2017-11-22 22:11:54.482  INFO 8988 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : cb8625948210849f
2017-11-22 22:11:54.482 DEBUG 8988 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : Kafka producer started
2017-11-22 22:11:54.484 DEBUG 8988 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Initialize connection to node -1 for sending metadata request
2017-11-22 22:11:54.484 DEBUG 8988 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Initiating connection to node -1 at 127.0.0.1:9093.
2017-11-22 22:11:54.485 DEBUG 8988 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-sent
2017-11-22 22:11:54.485 DEBUG 8988 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-received
2017-11-22 22:11:54.485 DEBUG 8988 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Added sensor with name node--1.latency
2017-11-22 22:11:54.485 DEBUG 8988 --- [ad | producer-1] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
2017-11-22 22:11:54.486 DEBUG 8988 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Completed connection to node -1.  Fetching API versions.
2017-11-22 22:11:54.486 DEBUG 8988 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Initiating API versions fetch from node -1.
2017-11-22 22:11:54.488 DEBUG 8988 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Recorded API versions for node -1: (Produce(0): 0 to 5 [usable: 3], Fetch(1): 0 to 6 [usable: 5], Offsets(2): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], Metadata(3): 0 to 5 [usable: 4], LeaderAndIsr(4): 0 to 1 [usable: 0], StopReplica(5): 0 [usable: 0], UpdateMetadata(6): 0 to 4 [usable: 3], ControlledShutdown(7): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], OffsetCommit(8): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], OffsetFetch(9): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], FindCoordinator(10): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], JoinGroup(11): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], Heartbeat(12): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], LeaveGroup(13): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], SyncGroup(14): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DescribeGroups(15): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], ListGroups(16): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], SaslHandshake(17): 0 to 1 [usable: 0], ApiVersions(18): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], CreateTopics(19): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DeleteTopics(20): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DeleteRecords(21): 0 [usable: 0], InitProducerId(22): 0 [usable: 0], OffsetForLeaderEpoch(23): 0 [usable: 0], AddPartitionsToTxn(24): 0 [usable: 0], AddOffsetsToTxn(25): 0 [usable: 0], EndTxn(26): 0 [usable: 0], WriteTxnMarkers(27): 0 [usable: 0], TxnOffsetCommit(28): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeAcls(29): 0 [usable: 0], CreateAcls(30): 0 [usable: 0], DeleteAcls(31): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeConfigs(32): 0 [usable: 0], AlterConfigs(33): 0 [usable: 0], UNKNOWN(34): 0, UNKNOWN(35): 0, UNKNOWN(36): 0, UNKNOWN(37): 0)
2017-11-22 22:11:54.489 DEBUG 8988 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Sending metadata request (type=MetadataRequest, topics=boot.test) to node -1
2017-11-22 22:11:54.493  WARN 8988 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {boot.test=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2017-11-22 22:11:54.523 DEBUG 8988 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Sending metadata request (type=MetadataRequest, topics=boot.test) to node -1
2017-11-22 22:11:54.528  WARN 8988 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 5 : {boot.test=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2017-11-22 22:11:54.593 DEBUG 8988 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Sending metadata request (type=MetadataRequest, topics=boot.test) to node -1
2017-11-22 22:11:54.600  WARN 8988 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {boot.test=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2017-11-22 22:11:54.628 DEBUG 8988 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Sending metadata request (type=MetadataRequest, topics=boot.test) to node -1
2017-11-22 22:11:54.633  WARN 8988 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 6 : {boot.test=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2017-11-22 22:11:54.700 DEBUG 8988 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Sending metadata request (type=MetadataRequest, topics=boot.test) to node -1
2017-11-22 22:11:54.705  WARN 8988 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 3 : {boot.test=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
```

**This is Kafka container logs:**

```
waiting for kafka to be ready
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,203] INFO KafkaConfig values:
        advertised.host.name = null
        advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://172.17.0.6:9093
        advertised.port = null
        alter.config.policy.class.name = null
        authorizer.class.name =
        auto.create.topics.enable = true
        auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
        background.threads = 10
        broker.id = -1
        broker.id.generation.enable = true
        broker.rack = null
        compression.type = producer
        connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
        controlled.shutdown.enable = true
        controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
        controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
        controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
        create.topic.policy.class.name = null
        default.replication.factor = 1
        delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1
        delete.topic.enable = true
        fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
        group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms = 0
        group.max.session.timeout.ms = 300000
        group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
        host.name =
        inter.broker.listener.name = null
        inter.broker.protocol.version = 1.0-IV0
        leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
        leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
        listener.security.protocol.map = PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
        listeners = PLAINTEXT://:9092
        log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
        log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
        log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
        log.cleaner.enable = true
        log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
        log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
        log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
        log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
        log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
        log.cleaner.threads = 1
        log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
        log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
        log.dirs = /kafka/kafka-logs-b0311aaa4e60
        log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
        log.flush.interval.ms = null
        log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
        log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
        log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
        log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
        log.message.format.version = 1.0-IV0
        log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
        log.preallocate = false
        log.retention.bytes = -1
        log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
        log.retention.hours = 168
        log.retention.minutes = null
        log.retention.ms = null
        log.roll.hours = 168
        log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
        log.roll.jitter.ms = null
        log.roll.ms = null
        log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
        log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
        max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
        max.connections.per.ip.overrides =
        message.max.bytes = 1000012
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        min.insync.replicas = 1
        num.io.threads = 8
        num.network.threads = 3
        num.partitions = 1
        num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
        num.replica.fetchers = 1
        offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
        offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
        offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
        offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
        offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
        offsets.retention.minutes = 1440
        offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
        offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
        offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
        offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
        port = 9092
        principal.builder.class = null
        producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
        queued.max.request.bytes = -1
        queued.max.requests = 500
        quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
        quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
        quota.window.num = 11
        quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
        replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
        replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
        replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
        replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
        replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
        replica.lag.time.max.ms = 10000
        replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
        replication.quota.window.num = 11
        replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
        sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
        security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
        socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
        socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.client.auth = none
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 60000
        transaction.max.timeout.ms = 900000
        transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 3600000
        transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
        transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
        transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
        transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 1
        transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
        transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
        unclean.leader.election.enable = false
        zookeeper.connect = zookeeper:2181
        zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 6000
        zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 6000
        zookeeper.set.acl = false
        zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000
 (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,278] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,279] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on zookeeper:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,291] INFO Starting ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,296] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.10-39d3a4f269333c922ed3db283be479f9deacaa0f, built on 03/23/2017 10:13 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,297] INFO Client environment:host.name=b0311aaa4e60 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,297] INFO Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_144 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,297] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,297] INFO Client environment:java.home=/opt/jdk1.8.0_144/jre (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,297] INFO Client environment:java.class.path=:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b32.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/..(org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,297] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,297] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,297] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,297] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,297] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,297] INFO Client environment:os.version=4.9.49-moby (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,297] INFO Client environment:user.name=root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,297] INFO Client environment:user.home=/root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,297] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/ (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,298] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=zookeeper:2181 sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@1534f01b (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,309] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper/172.17.0.4:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,309] INFO Waiting for keeper state SyncConnected (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,313] INFO Socket connection established to zookeeper/172.17.0.4:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
...
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,952] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1001-topic]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,956] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1001-Heartbeat]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,957] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1001-Rebalance]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,960] INFO Result of znode creation is: OK (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,972] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,973] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,978] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=1001] Removed 0 expired offsets in 5 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2017-11-22 20:32:16,988] INFO [ProducerId Manager 1001]: Acquired new producerId block (brokerId:1001,blockStartProducerId:0,blockEndProducerId:999) by writing to Zk with path version 1 (kafka.coordinator.transaction.ProducerIdManager)
[2017-11-22 20:32:17,004] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=1001] Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2017-11-22 20:32:17,005] INFO [Transaction Marker Channel Manager 1001]: Starting (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionMarkerChannelManager)
[2017-11-22 20:32:17,005] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=1001] Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2017-11-22 20:32:17,039] INFO Creating /brokers/ids/1001 (is it secure? false) (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2017-11-22 20:32:17,043] INFO Result of znode creation is: OK (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2017-11-22 20:32:17,044] INFO Registered broker 1001 at path /brokers/ids/1001 with addresses: EndPoint(172.17.0.6,9093,ListenerName(PLAINTEXT),PLAINTEXT) (kafka.utils.ZkUtils)
[2017-11-22 20:32:17,046] WARN No meta.properties file under dir /kafka/kafka-logs-b0311aaa4e60/meta.properties (kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint)
[2017-11-22 20:32:17,064] INFO Kafka version : 1.0.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2017-11-22 20:32:17,064] INFO Kafka commitId : aaa7af6d4a11b29d (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2017-11-22 20:32:17,065] INFO [KafkaServer id=1001] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-11-22 20:32:17,100] WARN [Controller id=1001, targetBrokerId=1001] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-11-22 20:32:17,208] WARN [Controller id=1001, targetBrokerId=1001] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-11-22 20:32:17,308] WARN [Controller id=1001, targetBrokerId=1001] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-11-22 20:32:17,410] WARN [Controller id=1001, targetBrokerId=1001] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

What is wrong there ?

Comment: I'd like to see the app what's connecting to Kafka. Is it inside the docker network of Kafka? or outside?

Comment: This app is Spring Boot application and is outside of Docker Kafka container. This app is located in the Docker host system.

Comment: so first it connects to 9093, then goes to zookeeper, and tries to go to 9092 as it seems. the advertised port setting is not picked up. what if you try to look into zookeeper at runtime? what's in there?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have provided `<KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT>9093</KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT>` and this way I got another error: `Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {boot.test=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}`

Comment: But the app is not running in a container is it? I faced this problem so many times a couple of months ago....

Comment: Yep, app is not running in a container

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159620/discussion-between-balazs-maria-nemeth-and-alexanoid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace localhost with the actual IP address of your host. Localhost means something different inside a container. Leader not available means that it cannot reach the broker for some reason.